# How to determine the number of bits in int

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

This is what I tried:

```
int i=-1,size=1;
while (i>>1)
    size++;
printf("%d",size);
```

The goal is to determine the size of `int` without using the `sizeof` operator.

The  above loop turns out to be infinite. Is there a way to fix it so it does what it is intended to do?

Comment: "Give me some solution." Of course... not. Begin with being polite.

Comment: Right shifting a signed integral value is implementation defined, but will usually do sign extension.  Using the corresponding unsigned type will solve the immediate problem, but the correct solution _is_ to use `sizeof`.

Comment: Guessing this is some sort of homework assignment.

Comment: Upvoting. This is not a bad question at all, even though the wording was a bit terse initially.

Comment: `(size_t)(((int *)0)+1)`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: `* CHAR_BIT` you mean?

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function.

Comment: @undur_gongor size of int

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: In the context of this question, "size of" refers to the number of bits (see the title and the code).

Comment: @undur_gongor I thought code seems to count a bit (if unsigned i and i >>= 1), to be sure goals  The final thing and ask the size of the int.

Comment: include limits header file and set the integer to max limit. then keep on dividing by 2 until 0. the number of iterations is the size of integer. kind of workaround but not efficient at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `unsigned` for `i`, rather than `int`.  They are
guaranteed to have the same size, and right shift of a signed integer is implementation defined (but will usually shift in the sign bit).  And don't forget to divide
the results by `CHAR_BIT` (which is *not* guaranteed to be 8).

Comment: +1, but re "And don't forget to divide the results by CHAR_BIT (which is not guaranteed to be 8)." - the question asks for the number of bits. (It does say "without using sizeof" but that's not saying a clone of `sizeof` is wanted.)

Comment: @TonyD Yes.  I saw the reference to `sizeof`, and reacted to that.  The number of bits is more complex, since it has two different definitions: his algorithm aims to return the number of value bits; `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)` would return the actual number of bits.  (But machines where there is a difference should be very rare.)

Answer (score 2):

You have chosen a negative number for right-shifting.
Right shifting a negative number, it gets filled with the sign bit 1 (or not, depending on implementation), so your value can never be 0 (=false), which means you get precisely the infinite loop you are complaining about.

Answer (score -1):

your loop is indeed infinite.
start from i = 1 and shift it left till you reach i =0 and stop. you have the bits.

-edit---
this will work for signed as well as unsigned integer alike.

Comment: ... except that it is undefined behavior for signed integers (in C at least).